# mamba nothing provides requested compilers

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros, miniconda, mamba

I am trying to install some packages with mamba, but encountering a problem where it can't seem to find the packages to install. I first installed miniconda, then I installed mamba using `conda install mamba -c conda-forge`. Then I created an environment (following the instructions to install robostack) `mamba create -n robostackenv ros-noetic-desktop python=3.9 -c robostack -c robostack-experimental -c conda-forge --no-channel-priority --override-channels`. Lastly, I tried to install some packages, like cmake and catkin_tools, but it is unable to find them. The commands that I ran were `mamba install compilers cmake pkg-config make ninja` and `mamba install catkin_tools`, and the results that I got were

```
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested compilers
```

[image]

Is there anything that I need to do to for it to find these packages?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was able to specify the source of the packages using the -c argument, and then I found both the "compilers" package and the "catkin_tools" package on conda-forge. So the updated (working) commands were then:
`mamba install compilers -c conda-forge`
`mamba install catkin_tools -c conda-forge`